# SSR suggestions for Vue 3 SPA

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vuejs3

I'm looking to develop a SPA with Vue 3 that will be deployed as a PWA. I was banking on Nuxt to provide support for Server Side Rendering, however, Nuxt Composition API doesn't seem to be a good option yet for production (at least until Nuxt 3 is released).

Since I'm looking to launch my site within the next few months, does anyone have any stable recommendations for Vue 3 compatible SSR solutions that are available today?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need Vue3 for?

Comment: Im building a PWA to run on AWS Fargate

Comment: Nothing really Vue3 specific so. ☺️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could recommend Quasar framework. The best by far: [Quasar](https://next.quasar.dev/introduction-to-quasar)

Comment: Good find! Quasar indeed do have a Vue3 support since few days! https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/9734 Not sure if it's the best by far but it is okay IMO.

Comment: Im glad it works for you, i have done alot of research in vue frameworks. Quasar, really, was the best for complex UI's of large enterprise app that we are building.

Comment: the fact that this does support a simple bootstrap of mobile apps is even better tbh!